# SharePoint - Change Completed Ontime Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Please I need help, I need the formula to show Completed Ontime = YES (Only if the task has been completed on time from the Start date to Due date) If not completed on time then to show NO.

Please see the picture attached.

Thank you all in advance.

[See my SharePoint List - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY3Gx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Simple test based on calculated column for your reference:

```
=IF(AND([% Complete]=1,[Task Status]="Completed"),"Yes","No")
```